# Postgres: Why is my delete query using up all available disk space?

Tags: postgresql, linux, timescaledb

I have a postgres table set up like so:

```
                                                           Table "public.facts"
   Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |              Default              | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id          | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('facts_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 value       | character varying(100)   |           |          |                                   | extended |              | 
 measured_at | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |                                   | plain    |              | 
 received_at | timestamp with time zone |           |          |                                   | plain    |              | 
 written_at  | timestamp with time zone |           |          |                                   | plain    |              | 
 is_numeric  | boolean                  |           |          |                                   | plain    |              | 
 source_id   | character varying(100)   |           |          |                                   | extended |              | 
 site_id     | integer                  |           |          |                                   | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "facts_measured_at_idx" btree (measured_at DESC)
    "facts_source_id_measured_at_idx" btree (source_id, measured_at)
    "idx_source_id_measured_at" btree (source_id, measured_at)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "facts_site_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (site_id) REFERENCES site(id)
    "facts_source_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (source_id) REFERENCES source(id)
Triggers:
    ts_insert_blocker BEFORE INSERT ON facts FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION _timescaledb_internal.insert_blocker()
Child tables: _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_100_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_101_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_102_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_103_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_104_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_105_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_106_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_107_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_108_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_109_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_110_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_111_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_112_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_113_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_114_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_115_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_116_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_117_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_118_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_119_chunk,
```

Recently a bug was introduced that caused an infinite loop and many thousands of duplicate rows were written. I want to delete those duplicate rows and I'm using the following query:

```
DELETE FROM facts a USING facts b WHERE a.id > b.id AND a.source_id = b.source_id AND a.measured_at = b.measured_at AND a.value = b.value;
```

Disk usage prior to running the query:

```
ubuntu@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G  844K  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1   49G  8.5G   40G  18% /
tmpfs            32G   44K   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       29M   29M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/2012
/dev/loop1       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10126
/dev/loop2       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10185
/dev/nvme1n1p1  3.9T  181G  3.5T   5% /mnt                <-- database on this volume
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1000
```

disk usage 3 days after executing the query (still running):

```
ubuntu@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G  836K  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1   49G  8.5G   40G  18% /
tmpfs            32G   44K   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       29M   29M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/2012
/dev/loop1       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10126
/dev/loop2       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10185
/dev/nvme1n1p1  3.9T  3.2T  527G  86% /mnt              <-- database on this volume
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Nothing is being written to or read from the database while this query is executing. Most of the extra storage is in `/mnt/postgres/12/main/base/pgsql_tmp`. Why does it take >3TB to delete less than 200GB?

Please let me know if there's any other info I can provide.

Comment: Maybe because of the fact that data must be consistent, and you doing a delete with one transaction? You can try to do the delete in chunks and see a disk usage. It is all just a guess.

Comment: "*many thousands of duplicate rows*" and it's taking days? Something is very wrong. Either you're having locking issues, or the query is extremely inefficient (could be missing indexes), or your idea of the count is very off. Running an `explain` would help, as would checking if the query is blocked. Otherwise I agree with yvw, it could be building a huge transaction. Or the disk usage could be completely unrelated!

Comment: 1) you don't have a PK/index on `id` 2) You don't have a supporting index for the FK `Foreign-key constraints:
    "facts_site_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (site_id) REFERENCES site(id)`

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts/insight! My initial count was indeed way off. That table has more like 600M rows and I suspect more than half are duplicates (infinite loops suck!). I ran an explain on the delete query and the output is about 4Mb, mostly dealing with hypertables. I'm thinking if I delete those, re-run the query, then re-create them this might go a lot more smoothly. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out all the extra child tables/chunks created by timescaledb were making this query run wild; running `EXPLAIN` as Schwern suggested was what keyed me into this. So here's what I ended up doing:

```sql
-- copy the table without any of the extra indices or child tables
CREATE TABLE facts_copy AS TABLE facts;

-- re-run the delete query, took about 23 hours, deleted 369225431 / 619858486 rows
DELETE FROM facts_copy a USING facts_copy b WHERE a.id > b.id AND a.source_id = b.source_id AND a.measured_at = b.measured_at AND a.value = b.value;

-- add fkeys and unique index so this can't happen again
ALTER TABLE facts_copy ADD CONSTRAINT facts_site_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (site_id) REFERENCES site(id);
ALTER TABLE facts_copy ADD CONSTRAINT facts_source_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (source_id) REFERENCES source(id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_idx_source_id_measured_at ON facts_copy(source_id,measured_at);

-- drop the old table and rename the new one
DROP TABLE facts;
ALTER TABLE facts_copy RENAME TO facts;

-- re-create the hypertable
SELECT create_hypertable('facts','measured_at',migrate_data=>true);
```